# Proving that the group of holomorphic automorphisms of the Riemann Sphere $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ are the Möbius Transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-surfaces, automorphism-group

Is the following proof correct?

**Proof:** Let $F\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}_\infty)$. Let $L:\mathbb{C}_\infty\to\mathbb{C}_\infty$ be a Möbius transformation that maps $F^{-1}(\infty)$ to $\infty$. For example, one can take
$$ L(z) = \dfrac{1}{z-F^{-1}(\infty)}. $$
Then $G=F\circ L\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}_\infty)$ and $G(\infty)=\infty$. This means that the restriction of G to the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ and hence
$$ G(z) = (F\circ L)(z) = az+b, $$
for some $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ with $a\neq 0$. This means
$$F = aL^{-1}(z) + b $$
which is a Möbius transformation.

Comment: Looks OK, assuming you've already proved elsewhere that the only holomorphic automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are linear. (Also, as a nitpick, $L$ isn't the only such transformation). A bit more abstractly, you're showing that the group $G$ of Mobius transformations acts transitively on $\mathbb{C}_\infty
$ and that the stabilizer of a point is a subgroup of $G$, which implies here that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}_\infty)$ is $G$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. First I thought maybe you needed this fact to calculate automorphisms of the plane (a fact you use in this proof), but it's not.